# Lighthouse - Low CLS score makes LCP score higher

Tags: lighthouse, cumulative-layout-shift

I'm trying to fix my website's performance issues mentioned in Lighthouse check.
The highest (which is bad) score is for CLS.

In order to solve CLS problems in website, all I need to do is to move some media queries styles that are loaded in the bottom of `<body>` to be loaded in `<head>`.
Means, moving styles from one CSS file to another.

After I do those changes, the CLS score decreases to be **0**! which is perfect.
**BUT** for some reason, once I do it, the LCP score multipates itself by 3!
No new requests, no additional CSS, no additional JS. And it still happends.

Has someone faced that issue? I really have no idea what to do.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not loading CSS asynchronously, then linking a CSS file in the head can effectively increase the loading time.

So it's not the CLS influencing LCP, it's just that the solution to one problem is causing a new one.

Try moving the smallest portion of your CSS that still fixes the issue to a new file, and then load only that file in the head.